# Habilitar os Stack Snippets aqui

Tags: novo-recurso, status-pronto, edição, stack-snippets

Conforme sugerido [no blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets), estou abrindo um pedido de novo recurso para que seja habilitado no nosso site. Para quem não conhece, esse recurso é novo e permite rodar código HTML+CSS+JS na própria resposta, muitas vezes eliminando a necessidade de uso do [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: basicamente é o farewell do jsfiddle; poder rodar código web aqui dentro é tudo de bom; tá demoraaaando!

Comment: Muito bacana esse recurso. Espero um dia ver um desses para substituir o SQLFiddle aqui ou no http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: 18 de setembro, 22:01 UTC, rev 2014.9.17.1862 . . . . Nada ainda... grrrrrrrr...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gccjv2eb/embedded/result/ @brasofilo

Comment: lolololol2much2lol :) bacana, nosso caça-níquel só tem duas opções!

Comment: Um pouco mais de paciência, que no máximo semana que vem entra no ar aqui. Talvez antes. Adivinha a causa: precisa traduzir as strings do recurso pra PT (e talvez faltem também outros ajustes de internacionalização). @brasofilo

Comment: Então falta colocar o i18n no wheel: http://jsfiddle.net/gccjv2eb/2/

Comment: Hahaha, coitado do cara! @brasofilo

Comment: Pensei "aposto que deve ter alguém com esse nome no SO". Efectivamente :)